# How to fire c# procedure when clicking on jQuery tabs?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I have 2 tabs.

- The first one is the most important and it loads the content very fast.
- The second one is not very important and it takes too long to load its content (charts and summaries)

So, I do not want to load both tabs' content at the same time. Ideally, I would just load the first tab content and when the user clicks on the second tab I would load its related content (on demmand).

In order to do that, I need to know in server side that the second tab has been clicked and then send back all the relevant information to the client side.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: use on click jquery event on <li> item and then make ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you will have to make changes on both client and server side.
On server side (or code-behind), make the method Static and decorate it with [WebMethod] attribute.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ...
    [WebMethod]
    public static void MethodToBeCalledUsingAjax(parameters)
    {
        //tab clicked logic goes here
    }
    ...
}
```

On client side, inside tab click function, use jquery ajax as below

```
var req = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Default.aspx/MethodToBeCalledUsingAjax",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
```

This ajax call shall on demand inform server side that the tab is clicked and process the code accordingly.

Please ignore the styling...i'm new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Good idea... Unfortunately I need to populate asp.net chart controls in my aspx from that webmethod, which is not possible due to the static keyword

Comment: ah right! then I guess there won't be easy approach unless you plan on using complete javascript chart controls like Highcharts or Raphaël.

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery UI tabs control supports [AJAX content](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) populated tabs. Just set the `href` for the tab links to your server side URL that will return the HTML content.

E.g:

```
<div id="my-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="myfirst-link" href="/Server/One">First</a></li>
        <li><a id="mysecond-link" href="/Server/Another">Second</a></li>   
    </ul>
</div>

$('#my-tabs').tabs({
    load: function (event, ui) {           
        switch (ui.tab.id) {
            case 'myfirst-link':
                break;
            case 'mysecond-link':
                break;
        }
    },
    ajaxOptions: {
        success: function(result) {
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
        }           
    }
});
```

If you need to run any Javascript when the tab has completed loading, then you can use the `load` event. If you need to handle any success or error's for each ajax call globally, then you can use `ajaxOptions`.

Comment: won't this approach load both pages at the same time? or will this load each page depending on the tab the user has clicked?

Comment: It will load the appropriate page as and when each tab is clicked. When the load is complete, the load event will fire, and you can check which link caused the load event to fire and run any JavaScript appropriate for that tab.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery-UI Tabs: Content via AJAX` to populate the tab. Source: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Here is the code (grabbed from above link):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                    $( anchor.hash ).html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Sample Text</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: won't this approach load both pages at the same time? or will this load each page depending on the tab the user has clicked?

Comment: This will load each page depending on the tab the user has clicked. The page loaded is dependant upon the href value in the link for a given tab: `<li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li> `

Comment: So, you are saying that every time the user clicks on a tab the page will be loaded, right?

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't found how to fire an event in the codebehind when clicking on the jQuery tab, it is possible to do this with [JuiceUI Tabs](http://juiceui.com/controls/tabs) with the `SelectedTabChanged` event handler

Answer (score 0):

You should not wait for the user to click on the second tab. Rather what you can do is, fill up the first tab on document.onReady event. It should fetch the content of first tab using ajax requested.

Once you get reply of the first ajax request, on the reply callback, make a new request for the second tab. This way, it will load in background while the user is dealing with the first tab and when he/she switches to second, it will also be ready.

Use this in your document

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var req = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Default.aspx/MethodToBeCalledUsingAjax",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
});
```

in the success: function, put code for loading the second tab.

Comment: Good idea... Unfortunately I need to populate asp.net chart controls in my aspx from that webmethod, which is not possible due to the static keyword

Comment: I don't see any issue in populating chart control. If you could post some code, I can help you out with this

Comment: The issue is that I cannot access any control from a webmethod... I appreciate your help anyway